# iPhone / iPad / iPod swipe events javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, ipod, swipe

Im looking for (if possible) javascript libraries/plugins to provide swipe events.

However I am not after the simple detection of a swipe, for example what jqTouch provides. I wish to create behavior similar to that of the images viewer on the iPod devices. So for example you drag left or right to go to the next image. You have to drag the image over 50% of the way and let go and it will snap to the next image. If you do not drag 50% of the image, it just snaps back to the original.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like the [Carousel component](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/carousel) in Sencha Touch (view on iPad/iPhone or Chrome/Safari). This has the behavior you want built in. [I work for Sencha]

Comment: Thats just brilliant! Thanks. Are t here any APIs for this component? How do I make it not set the scale and scroll on the iPhone?

Comment: Yes it's part of an SDK - so you should look at dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs for the API

Comment: You're the man, Michael! No other libs (including jQuery Mobile) can do this so smooth like this one!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a standalone solution for your problem:

http://swipejs.com/

The more general solution to javascript swipe events can be found here:

https://github.com/eikes/jquery.swipe-events.js